# How to call JavaScript methods on jQuery objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer-8

Let's go straight to the point.

The following code must run on IE8, unfortunately.

It is supposed to find match the URL of the current page with the `href` attribute of the `<a>` tags present in the *nav*. Then swap the class of that tag from `not-selected` to `selected` or defaults to do it to the first `<a>` tag.

**HTML**

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li><a class="not-selected" href="index.php"><span>Index Page</span></a></li>
    <li>
        <a class="not-selected" href="page1.php"><span>Page 1</span></a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a class="not-selected" href="page2.php"><span>Page 2</span></a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**JavaScript (jQuery)**

```
var url = $(document).attr('URL');

var isIndexPage = true;

var menu = $('#nav').children('li');

var anchors = menu.find('a');

anchors.each(function(index) {

    //   Is the href the same as the page?
    if ($(this).href != null && anchor.href == url)
    {
        $(this).first().addClass('selected');
        if ($(this).className.match(/\bnot\-selected\b/))
        $(this).first().removeClass('not-selected');

        indexPage = false;
     }
     else
     {
         //   remove class="selected" if it has that class
         if ($(this).className.match(/\bselected\b/))
         {
             $(this).first().removeClass('selected');
         }
         //   Add class="trigger"
         $(this).first().addClass('not-selected');                    
      }
 });

 if (isIndexPage)
 {
     menu[0].childNodes[0].setAttribute('class', 'selected');
 }
```

On the script, I get an error on the line that calls the `match()` function on the `className` attribute (which should be a string).

Why is that?

How can I fix it with jQuery or JavaScript that works on IE8?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why don't you use the [**jQuery's .hasClass**](https://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) instead of `className.match` ?

Comment: What is the expected result of your code? And what exactly is the issue you're running into?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no `className` property of the jQuery object, you would use the `hasClass` method to check if the element has a class:

```
if ($(this).hasClass('not-selected'))
```

However, you don't need that check at all. You can just remove the class, and if it's not there in the first place the call will just do nothing. You can just do it like this:

```
$(this).addClass('selected').removeClass('not-selected');
```

Similarly in the `else` block, you don't need to check, just remove and add:

```
$(this).removeClass('selected').addClass('not-selected');
```

---

Actually, you don't even need the `if`, you can do it using `toggleClass` and a boolean value. This would be your entire loop:

```
anchors.each(function() {
  var sel = $(this).href != null && $(this).href == url;
  $(this).toggleClass('selected', sel).toggleClass('not-selected', !sel);
});
```

---

Also, you are using the undefined variable `anchor` where you should use `$(this)`. Change this line:

```
if ($(this).href != null && anchor.href == url)
```

to:

```
if ($(this).href != null && $(this).href == url)
```

Comment: I caught the anchor problem after posting and will change it. The other answers are correct. But this one was insightful and taught me how to write better (cleaner) code. Accepted. Thank you.

Comment: I also checked that I need `$(this).prop('href')` rather than `$(this).attr('href')` so the checks actually compare entire HTML paths.

Answer (score 0):

`className` is a native property of HTML elements, whereas you're trying to call it as a property on a jQuery object. Do either:

```
$(this)[0].className
```

or

```
$(this).attr('class')
```

Sidenote: you're are not first checking whether the element has a class or not - you're assuming it has. The second (jQuery) approach will error if the element has no `class` attribute, as it returns `null` if none is found (as opposed to the native `className` property which, in the absence of a corresponding `class` attribute, defaults to an empty string.)

Answer (score 0):

you can replace the lines

```
if ($(this).className.match(/\bselected\b/))
```

with this

```
if ($(this).hasClass('selected'));
```

It's much simpler. The same for class 'not-selected'.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use plain JS for the URL and jQuery for the rest example:

**JavaScript**

```
var path = window.location.pathname;

$.each($('#nav li a'), function(index, anchor) {
    if(path.indexOf($(anchor).attr('href')) != -1) {
        $('#nav li a').removeClass('selected');
        $(anchor).addClass('selected').removeClass('not-selected');
    }
});
```

Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/2rSqL/